# Jquery - How to transition (fadeIn/fadeOut) back and forth between html elements and keep position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$("#firstPageNextArrow").fadeOut(200, function() {
    $("#p2Head").fadeIn("medium", function() {
        $("#p2tip").fadeIn("medium", function (){
            $("#factorInputs").fadeIn("medium", function() {
                $("#addFactor").fadeIn("medium",function() {
                    $("#secondPageBackArrow").fadeIn("medium");
                    $("#secondPageNextArrow").fadeIn("medium");
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Above is some code to show how I've been going about things.

So I've been using the fadeOut and fadeIn methods to transition back and forth between "pages", or technically just the inner html elements. It's been going okay so far, but the positioning of the containing divs aren't stable. To cut to the chase: Are there more efficient ways to transition to new/old html elements that also preserve positioning?

Comment: Better if you could create a similar demo in **Snippet** or **[JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)**

Answer (score 2):

You have to set their position to `absolute` because when the transition is start, the both of the `div`s are with `display:block` and that what causes to the `position` problem.

**The problem**

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('div').each(function(){
    var elem = $(this);
    if (elem.is(':visible')) {
      elem.fadeOut();
    }
    else {
      elem.fadeIn();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

#div1 {
  background:red; 
}

#div2 {
  background:green;  
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<button>Toggle</button>
```

**The solution**

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('div').each(function(){
    var elem = $(this);
    if (elem.is(':visible')) {
      elem.fadeOut();
    }
    else {
      elem.fadeIn();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute; /* this is the change */
}

#div1 {
  background:red; 
}

#div2 {
  background:green;  
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Toggle</button>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Keep it in your mind that you need to take care about the rest of the content. Read more about [`position:absolute`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

Comment: Is this answer your question?